# Use node-formidable upload files, always get "Error Request Aborted"

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express, amazon-s3, formidable

I use Express(3.6.0) + formidable(latest) for upload files to S3.

When I submit post, I always got an Error `Request Aborted`.

`incoming_form.js`:

```
IncomingForm.prototype.parse = function(req, cb) {
...
  req
  .on('aborted', function() {
    self.emit('aborted');
    self._error(new Error('Request aborted'));
  })
...
}


[Error: Request aborted]
child process: Request aborted
Error: Request aborted
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous>      
(/node_modules/formidable/lib/incoming_form.js:107:19)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at abortIncoming (http.js:1911:11)
at Socket.serverSocketCloseListener (http.js:1923:5)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at TCP.close (net.js:465:12)
```

I want to know why I got aborted and how to debug it.